# CEP Proton - Consumer file overwritten

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I’m using CEP (Complex Event Processing) Proton FIWARE Generic Enabler and I've first created a project where I defined a Consumer that outputs certain types of events to a file.

I realised that every time that I need to restart the Java application (ProtonOnWebServer) the output file generated by the Consumer is overwritten. Is this the supposed behaviour or is there any append mode where all the previous events written to the file don’t get lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour.

Every time the CEP starts a new run, it re-writes the content of the output file. Currently it is not configurable.